# How to make the contents of a cells of a column stick to the top?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lL{.5\textwidth}}
    This should stick to the top. & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table picture latex]

I think the MWE is self-explanatory. How do I make the contents stick to the top?

Comment: It would be at the top by default but you have used the array package `m` column type to force it to the vertical centre

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used column type `m` so that I can declare the width of the column. Without using that column type, I can't declare the width. But it centers the text vertically, which I don't want. Any idea?

Comment: the standard paragraph column is `p` which is top aligned, `m` is an extension from the `array` package for vertical centre alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `p{..}` column type will align on the first line of text. Use that in place of the `m{..}` column type which is an extension from the `array` package for vertical centre (*m* iddle) alignment.